# Monitoring PolynomialReduce/Alternatives for other CAS packages

Tags: performance-tuning, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, groebner-bases

I have a large generic polynomial That looks like

$N = \sum_{i_1,i_2\cdots}c_{i_1,i_2,i_3,\cdots} {x_{1}}^{i_1}{x_{2}}^{i_2}\cdots $

This could have anywhere between 3000-9000 terms with a maximum degree of 7 in total for each term.

I need to reduce this by a grobner basis(which can be calculated relatively quickly) with about 8 elements.

$N = r+\sum_i q_i g_i$

where $g_i$'s are elements of a groebner basis.

Right now I am using PolynomialReduce[] which does seem to take it's own sweet time but gives me the answer I want. Is there anyway I can monitor Polynomial reduce to see how far it progressed/check if it is stuck.

I tried using the singular interface for mathematica, but that seems to be able to give me only the remainder. It was much faster however in returning the remained. Singular returned the remainder in 19 seconds for a case when PolynomialReduce took around 6 minutes (granted Polynomial reduce also gives me the "q_i's"). However singular crashes my mathematica kernel when I have a polynomial that is around 4000 terms large.

Suggestions for alternate CAS packages that can potentially do a better job at this than mathematica/ alternate ways to do this are welcome.

I would prefer to keep it analytical, because this is result is something that I will have to reuse multiple times, so I would like to avoid having to go through this procedure of reduction multiple times for each point.

I am not extremely familiar with computational algebra, so I apologize in advance for any ignorance/improper use of terminology in my question.

Edit: I have included a simple sample test case.

```
variables = {xx[1, 1], xx[1, 2], xx[1, 3], xx[1, 4], xx[2, 1], xx[2, 2], xx[2, 3], xx[2, 4], y[1, 1], y[2, 1], y[2, 2]}; 

groebner = {-4 a^2 y[1, 2]^2 + 4 a^2 c y[2, 2], -2 a^2 c + 8 a^2 y[1, 1], -2 a c xx[2, 2] - a^2 c xx[2, 3] + 2 a y[1, 2], -2 a^2 xx[2, 1] - a^2 c xx[2, 3] - 2 a y[1, 2], a c - a^2 c xx[1, 3], a xx[1, 2], a + c + a xx[1, 1]}; 

res = PolynomialReduce[numerator, groebner, variables, MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic];
```

The numerator could be a generic polynomial that is constrained by power counting arguments. As a test example:

```
GenericPoly[func_, xs_] := 
 FromCoefficientRules[
  CoefficientRules[func, xs] /. HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] :> a -> f @@ a, 
  xs]

numerator = 
 GenericPoly[((1 + Total@variables) )^4, variables];
```

For this numerator Mathematica takes around 30 seconds, while SingularReduce returns the remainder in 3 seconds on my system.

If I increase the power to 5 in the numerator, Mathematica seems take a lot of time and I would like to somehow track it's progress if possible. I tried writing my own  PolynomialReduce code, but it is not as efficient as mathematica's. SingularReduce crashes the kernel when I try to run it.

I don't mind Mathematica taking slightly a long time as long as I can somewhat track progress to make sure that there is some reasonable end in sight.

Comment: Can you post a link to an explicit example?

Comment: For instance I could have 

variables = {xx[1, 1], xx[1, 2], xx[1, 3], xx[1, 4], xx[2, 1], 
   xx[2, 2], xx[2, 3], xx[2, 4], y[1, 1], y[2, 1], y[2, 2]};
groebner = {-4 a^2 y[1, 2]^2 + 4 a^2 c y[2, 2], -2 a^2 c + 
    8 a^2 y[1, 1], -2 a c xx[2, 2] - a^2 c xx[2, 3] + 
    2 a y[1, 2], -2 a^2 xx[2, 1] - a^2 c xx[2, 3] - 2 a y[1, 2], 
   a c - a^2 c xx[1, 3], a xx[1, 2], a + c + a xx[1, 1]};
res = PolynomialReduce[numerator, groebner, variables, 
   MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic];


Where the numerator could be large limited by degree arguments for each monomial

Comment: Would you make that explicit example part of your question rather than just having it in a comment?  Also, please show the resulting output.  You example in the comment is still incomplete because `numerator` is not defined.  It's harder to help when there isn't a complete example.

Comment: I do not have a good answer here. I can say that around 93% of the time is spent in preprocessing, prior to any actual reduction taking place. This is when I check in a debugging kernel. A production version might show a different ratio but I would expect it still to exceed 80% in preprocessing.

Comment: I will experiment with some heuristics that might avoid most of the preprocessing hit.